# Call a method from another JFrame

Tags: java

I want to get a JFrame (createFrame) from another JFrame (mainFrame). I created a method in the mainFrame which returns the createFrame, so that I can dispose the createFrame when clicking a button in the createFrame. But I cant call this methode (getCreateFrame) from the second JFrame (createFrame).

MainFrame.java

```
import frames.SelectFrame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JComboBox cbOption;
    private JButton btConfirm;
    private JLabel lbCredit;
    private JFrame createFrame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("");
        mainFrame.setContentPane(new MainFrame().mainPanel);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setBounds(500, 500, 400, 400);
    }

    public MainFrame() {
        btConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int option = cbOption.getSelectedIndex();
                System.out.println(option);
                if(option == 0){
                    JFrame createFrame = new SelectFrame();
                    createFrame.setContentPane(new SelectFrame().mainPanel);
                    createFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    createFrame.pack();
                    createFrame.setVisible(true);
                    createFrame.setBounds(500, 500, 400, 400);
                    System.out.println("Frame created!");
                } else if(option == 1){

                }  else{

                }
            }
        });
    }
    public final JFrame getCreateFrame(){
        return createFrame;
    }
}
```

CreateFrame.java

```
package frames;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Date;

public class SelectFrame extends JFrame{
    public JPanel mainPanel;
    private JLabel lbCredit;
    private JComboBox cbxCurrency;
    private JButton btConfirm;
    private JButton btExit;

    public SelectFrame() {
        btConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        btExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call getCreateFrame(), and what kind of error message do you get when you try to call it?

Comment: I want to call it in createClass in the action listener of the btExit button.

Comment: if you are new to java and have similar problems that might be "too easy" for stackoverflow you could check out my [github](https://github.com/darclander) for my discord if you want further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question I believe you should take a look at [Programming scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

If you want to access the `getCreateFrame()` method in your `SelectFrame`-class you will need to be able to *reach* the `MainFrame`-class somehow since this holds the method.

`createFrame` is a private variable of the `MainFrame`-class which means it's only accessible within the class. Which is why (as you have done) you need a get-method to retrieve it. Although, when you call the get-method you want to know which object's `createFrame` you are trying to access. The question is, how will `SelectFrame` know which method to call?

If you edit your `SelectFrame`-class alike this:

```
public class SelectFrame extends JFrame {

    private MainFrame mFrame;

    public SelectFrame(MainFrame frame) {
        mFrame = frame;
    }

}
```

You can now call the `getCreateFrame()` from the `MainFrame` you pass to `SelectFrame`'s constructor within the `SelectFrame` class. (`mFrame.getCreateFrame();`)

Note: In the `MainFrame`-class's constructor you initialize your `createFrame` in an `if`-statement which means it will give you `null` unless `option == 0`.

```
if(option == 0) {
    JFrame createFrame = new SelectFrame(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your returned createFrame is null. This is due to the fact that you have introduced an local instance of JFrame createFrame = new SelectFrame(); in the MainFram constructor

```
public final JFrame getCreateFrame(){
     return createFrame;
}
```

Comment: But how can I call this getCreateFrame(); method in the Action Listener in the SelectFrame class.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you are creating a local variable instead of assigning to the instance variable you created.

```
JFrame createFrame = new SelectFrame();
```

Should instead have been:

```
createFrame = new SelectFrame();
```

Don't create a new variable, assign to the existin one.

Comment: If you are going to press the ```btConfirm``` button more than once, check if ```createFrame``` is ```null``` and if it isn't, call ```createFrame.dispose()``` before assigning a new value to it. Otherwise, you will create more windows without actually destroying any of the previous ones.